# Converting a Bitmap to a String and saving it in a mySQL server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

My program takes a bitmap and converts it to a string, then saves that string in a myswl through php. I am not getting any response from my server which includes not getting an error.

Here is the JAVA portion:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
proPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
String image = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);         
entity.addPart("tag", new StringBody("register"));
entity.addPart("name", new StringBody(name));
entity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email));
entity.addPart("password", new StringBody(password));
entity.addPart("image", new StringBody(image));
```

Here is the php part:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$stringPic = $_POST['image'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];           
$profilePic=base64_decode($stringPic);
```

Comment: Please include the code that sends the stream to the server. Do you have the correct URL? Do your server logs indicate that a connection was attempted? Are there any errors in the server logs?

Comment: Why would you save images as strings (or even in original format) in a database? It's generally a really inefficient and inflexible way of handling images. Simply save the image "as is" somewhere on your server and then just add a URI string to the database.

Comment: Or if you insist on putting it in MySql use blob. Also wait for about 45 seconds at least before saying it doesn't give an error. I'm betting that PHP is in an infinite loop, and eventually apache will kill it, and tell you.